# Add random string to file upload ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Working on this code of Advanced Custom Fields (ACF), but it gives an error "Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file". If I remove srand() it works. Any ideas how to add a random string to the end of the filename, because that is the goal.

```
function acf_upload_prefilter() {
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'rename_current_acf_upload', 11, 1);
}
add_filter('acf/upload_prefilter/name=document_bestand', 'acf_upload_prefilter' );

function rename_current_acf_upload( $file ){
$file['name'] = date('Ymd').'-'.$file['name'].'-'.srand();
return $file;
}
```